# There is no Options in Hombrew for opencv installation

Tags: c++, opencv, homebrew

When I run this command on Terminal `brew info opencv` I get this answer:

```
opencv: stable 3.3.0 (bottled)
Open source computer vision library
http://opencv.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.0_3 (516 files, 122.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-08-27 at 01:15:27
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: eigen ✔, ffmpeg ✔, jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libtiff ✔, openexr ✔, numpy ✔
==> Requirements
Required: python ✔, python3 ✔
==> Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/amirhossein/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/amirhossein/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Where are the options like `--with--contrib`? How can I install opencv with contrib & other options using Homebrew?

Comment: Try `brew options opencv` or `brew options opencv3`

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens !!

Comment: Mmmm, not sure where all the options have gone, nor why. It is not too hard to install using `git clone` and `cmake` though.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no such option because Homebrew builds `opencv` with `contrib` *by default*. All the existing options were removed when `opencv` was imported into the core repository two weeks ago.

Just use `brew install opencv`.

Comment: I don't think so !

Comment: @user2626054 What do you mean?