# Installing OpenCV 3 on mac won't install jar

Tags: macos, opencv, homebrew

I am trying to install OpenCV3 on mac using:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv3 --HEAD --with-java
```

I would expect a jar lib in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.0_3/share/OpenCV
```

But there in no jar in the whole project.

(I also added `-DBUILD_opencv_java=ON` flag via `brew edit opencv3`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915660/2836621

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the very same issue with the **v3.3.0**. I was following the documentation that says basically the following:

- `brew edit opencv`
- change `-DBUILD_opencv_java=ON`
- `brew install --build-from-source opencv`

However, the `java` folder was missing in `usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.0_3/share/OpenCV`, although there was no error report.

Fortunately, I figured what was the issue: the OpenCV **requires** `ant` to be installed! It is used to build a jar after all the java sources are generated. So, the solution in my case was:

```
brew install ant
```

and then repeating the above procedure. Note that `--build-from-source` is required in order to get the jar.

Answer (score 3):

igr is right. we do need to install ant before we install opencv. 
If you have already installed opencv and then find out the jars are missing, then you need to install ant and  run the make on your own. I couldnt figure how to run the make. so I uninstalled opencv after installing ant and reinstalled opencv. and voila the jars were there as specified.

> ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1/share/OpenCV/java
>
> libopencv_java331.dylib   opencv-331.jar